# My first website in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, performance, beginner, react.js

I wrote my first working website in ReactJs as a beginner and I have a few questions.

First question is about `meta-tags`. I used `react-snap` for generate `meta-tags`, because it was the only solution I have found so far, that didnt use server side rendering. But, I have two pages on webpage, one for content and one for Cookies info and for Cookies page it didnt write any meta-tags or title. I could try to use SSR, but I dont know any other language for backend than `PHP` and I dont know how this two languages can work together with SSR. Do you have any recommendations? I also tried to use `react-helmet`, but for Facebook or Twitter it needs to use SSR.

I used react-snap like this in `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import { hydrate, render } from "react-dom";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
if (rootElement.hasChildNodes()) {
  hydrate(<App />, rootElement);
} else {
  render(<App />, rootElement);
}
```

Second question is about `iframe`s. Somewhere I saw that it is unsafe to pass `src` directly into the iframe. Is this the right way?

```
const map1 = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d652.403796164....";

<iframe
   src={map1}
   title="Mapa pobočky pro&nbsp;kamiony, autobusy a&nbsp;agro stroje"
   loading="lazy"
/>
```

Next question is with `react-spring`. I use it everywhere across the page and sometimes happen that when I goes to the Cookies page and return back through menu to main page, menu slides up with laggs. Can it be caused by the overlay on the video in main page in combine with text animations on the video?

I use this for the video in main page:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useTransition, animated, config } from 'react-spring';

import Video from "../images/bgVideo1.mp4";

const Slider = () =>{

  const texts = [
    {id: 0, text: "Chiptuning osobních aut"},
    {id: 1, text: "Chiptuning nákladních aut"},
    {id: 2, text: "Chiptuning zemědělské techniky"},
  ];

  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const textTransitions = useTransition(texts[index], (item) => item.id, {
    from: { opacity: 0, transform: "translate3d(0,-15%,0) scale3d(1,1.1,1)" },
    enter: { opacity: 1, transform: "translate3d(0,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1)" },
    leave: { opacity: 0, transform: "translate3d(0,15%,0) scale3d(1,0.95,1)" },
    config: config.gentle,
  });


  useEffect(() => void setInterval(() => setIndex((state) => (state + 1) % 3), 4000), []);

  return(
    <div className="sliderContainer">

      {textTransitions.map(({ item, props, key }) => (
        <animated.div className="sliderText" style={props} key={key} >
          <h1><span>A</span>utorizovaný chiptuning QUANTUM</h1>
          <p>{item.text}</p>
        </animated.div>
      ))}

      <div className="sliderVideo">

        <video
          src={Video}
          muted
          playsInline={true}
          autoPlay={true}
          loop
          disablePictureInPicture
        />

      </div>

    </div>
  );

}

export default Slider;
```

And this for the menu.. This is kinda messy I think, but it works somehow.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSpring, animated } from 'react-spring';

import Logo from "../images/Quantum-chiptuning-logo.png";
import AutoSlavkovLogo from "../images/auto-slavkov.png";

const Header = () => {

  const [isToggled, toggleMenu] = useState(false);
  const menuEffect = useSpring({
    opacity: isToggled ? 1 : .85,
    height: isToggled ? "50vh" : "0vh",
  });

  return(
    <header role="banner">

      <div className="container">

        <NavLink exact to="/" className="logo"><img src={ Logo } alt="logo" /></NavLink>

        <div
          className={`navButton ${isToggled ? "active" : "" }`}
          onClick={ () => toggleMenu(!isToggled)}
        >
          <div className="navButtonHamburger">
          </div>
          
        </div>

        <animated.nav style={menuEffect}>
          <ul>
            <li><NavLink exact to="/" onClick={ () => toggleMenu(false)}>ÚVOD</NavLink></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.quantumchiptuning.cz/kontakt" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" onClick={ () => toggleMenu(false)}>KONTAKT&nbsp;&nbsp;<i className="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
          <a href="https://www.autoslavkov.cz" className="menuSecondLogo" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" onClick={ () => toggleMenu(false)}><img src={ AutoSlavkovLogo } alt="AutoSlavkov Logo" /></a>
        </animated.nav>

      </div>

    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

And last question is about importing pictures and videos or other content like that. Is there any better way to import image to the component then this?

```
import Logo from "../images/Quantum-chiptuning-logo.png";
```

That's all what I want to know for now, I will be very grateful for your suggestions.

If you want to se website in action, link is here: https://www.chiptuning-brno.cz/ and my repository on GitHub is here: https://github.com/Kretiss/chiptuning-brno

Comment: You ask multiple questions in one post. This is genius.